# PHP use foreach multidimensional data outside it

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach

Having this php code:

```
$data['items'] =  array('cars', 'bikes', 'trains');
$data['title']   = $parameters['title'];

foreach ($searchResults as $key => $value)
{
    switch ($key)
    {
        case "_cars":
        foreach ($searchResults['_cars']['items'] as $car)
        {
            preg_match('@video/([^_]+)_([^/]+)@', $car['url'], $match);
            $url = $match[1].'/'.$match[2];
            $url = base_url().'video/'.substr($url,0,1).'d'.substr($url,1);

            $data['data']['car']['url']   = $url;
            $data['data']['car']['title'] = $car['title'];
            $data['data']['car']['img']   = $car['thumbnail_medium_url'];
        }
        break;
        // ................
```

How can I fix this, or what I am doing wrong because `$['data']['car'][...]` returns only 1 item for url, title and img outside `case "_cars": foreach...` but inside it does returns all the data.

Edit:
but I wonder why doing print_r($data) inside the `foreach ($searchResults['_cars']['items']...` loop returns all data and outside that `foreach` only 1?

Comment: It only returns 1 item because you're overwriting `$data` in your foreach loop.

Comment: it's not that... I am doing so because that's inside codeigniter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're wanting, but at first glance, it looks like each iteration is  overwriting the actual value of the array key:

```
$data['data']['car']['url'] = $url; // this is overwritten each time
```

You need to create an iterator and use that:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($searchResults['_cars']['items'] as $car)
{
  preg_match('@video/([^_]+)_([^/]+)@', $car['url'], $match);
  $url = $match[1].'/'.$match[2];
  $url = base_url().'video/'.substr($url,0,1).'d'.substr($url,1);

  $data['data']['car'][$i]['url']   = $url;
  $data['data']['car'][$i]['title'] = $car['title'];
  $data['data']['car'][$i]['img']   = $car['thumbnail_medium_url'];
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: but isn't any way to use it without having `$i`?

Comment: but I want why doing `print_r($data)` inside the `foreach ($searchResults['_cars']['items']...` loop returns all data and outside only 1?

Comment: @w0rldart, it's because you're overwriting `$date['data']['car']['XXX']` rather than adding another array value. It'd be like setting `$date_url = $url;` each iteration and expecting `$date_url` to be an array of data after. Also, the `$i` is to make sure the array key is the same for each one (esp. if these variables are overwritten again within the `foreach`). With your simple implementation, using `[]` instead of `[$i]` *would* work, but it's **not recommended**.

Comment: had to way for the minutes to pass in order to accept the answer :)